# how to get two tables data based on column

Tags: json, sqlite, cordova, join, inner-join

We have two tables Table1 and table2. Table1 have A,B,C columns and Table2 have B,E,F columns.

```
Table1                    Table2
A      B     C         B      E     F
raja   21   HYD        21     AP   60000000
raju   21   VJY        
ravi   21   BEG
```

We need is

```
A      B    C     E    F
raja   21   HYD   AP   60000000
raju   21   VJY   AP   60000000 
ravi   21   BEG   AP   60000000
```

so We tried like this

```
tx.executeSql('SELECT r.A as name,r.B as age,r.C as city,s.E as state,s.F as distance from table1 r Left JOIN table2 s on r.B=s.B',[],joinsuccess,errorCB);
    function joinsuccess(tx,result){
            var JOINLength = result.rows.length;
             for (var i=0; i<JOINLength; i++){
             console.log(result.rows.item(i).name);
             console.log(result.rows.item(i).age);
             console.log(result.rows.item(i).city);
             console.log(result.rows.item(i).state);
             console.log(result.rows.item(i).distance);
}
    }
```

but it's we got only

```
ravi   21   BEG  AP   60000000
```

Comment: because the b is not unique thats why you not get all the data of your table.

Comment: Your query is correct. You can check it by http://sqlfiddle.com/#!7/4c246/1 on chrome browser. Find the root of your problem elsewhere .

Comment: Unlike forum sites, we don't use "Thanks", or "Any help appreciated", or signatures on [so]. See "[Should 'Hi', 'thanks,' taglines, and salutations be removed from posts?](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/2950/should-hi-thanks-taglines-and-salutations-be-removed-from-posts). BTW, it's "Thanks in advance", not "Thanks in advanced".

Comment: Do you found a solution?
I have the same problem